# Maven same Classname in different dependencies

Tags: java, maven, dependency-management

i have a maven project that has two dependencies: `DependencyA` and `DependencyB`. In each of the dependencies there is a class, lets call it `FooClass`.

Now there is a problem, because one class of my project needs the `FooClass` of `DependencyA` and another class needs the `FooClass` of `DependencyB`. But both classes load the `FooClass` of `DependencyA`.

Can i solve this problem with maven? Or do i have to think about the design of my project structure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should avoid getting two classes with same name in same package. This would lead to the idea that you have two modules of different versions of one code...

It would not be an issue if you had for instance com.yourcompany.yourproyectA.FooClass and com.yourcompany.yourproyectB.FooClass.

This scenario happens often and I have never had an issue with maven.

Regards

Comment: The FooClass is not in the same package. Its not even in the same maven dependency.

Comment: If they are not in the same package, then there should be no issue. Make sure your import statements are correct.

Comment: Just to be clear, if you have two classes com.yourproject.FooClass in different maven dependencies, they're really the same class and that's where you can get issues, that's why I'm asking, if the package names are identical, they are the same package even though they are in separate dependencies.

Comment: One more thing, if you have one class that imports both classes, something like import com.yourprojectA.FooClass; and import com.yourprojectB.FooClass; then it will cause trouble, but it's not a maven issue but a Java thing. The compiler won't know which of the two you are referencing, in this case you can import the one you use most and reference the other with the full name, for example "com.yourprojectB.FooClass myObject = new com.yourprojectB.FooClass();". I'm not sure if that's your problem.

Comment: Well i think that's the point. The package names are identical. I didn't know that maven couldn't distinguish that.

Comment: Well, it's not that maven cannot do that, it's that the JVM will only be able to load one of the classes as both have the exact same name, you should have clear distniguishing names between packages, each maven module could have part of it's "reason to be" as part of the package name, so you won't run into this kind of issues.

Answer (score 1):

If two libraries need two different versions of the same library, I recommend to use a module system such as OSGi.